# MultiChoiceModeListener.onItemCheckedStateChanged() only executes when item is checked

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-checkbox

I'm having a problem.
In my main activity, which extends `ListActivity` and Implements `MultiChoiceModeListener`, I have the overriden method `onItemCheckedStateChanged()`.

The problem is that this method only gets executed when the new checked state of the itrem is CHECKED. If I uncheck it, it doesn't execute.

I check the item programatically from my `DataListAdapter`. My item layout contains a `CheckBox`, that when it's checked, i use the control's `onCheckedChanged()` to change the list item check state.

Any clues?

Here is my code (relevant code only):

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements MultiChoiceModeListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate (bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        setContentView (R.layout.main);

        this.getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        this.getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);

        _dataAdapter = new ServerListAdapter (this);
        this.getListView(). setAdapter(_dataAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu (this.getListView());
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        // Some code that only is executed when the setItemChecked is true on the DataListAdapter.        
    }
}
```

**List Adapter**

```
public class ServerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = (convertView == null ?
                _context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.server_list_item_view,
                parent, 
                false) : convertView);

        final ListView listView = (ListView)parent;
        ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chkItemServerSelected)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton pCompound, boolean arg1) 
            {
                listView.setItemChecked(position, pCompound.isChecked());
            }       
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to share what that code is that is only run if true? Or at least verify that the method isn't called when false?

Comment: @codeMagic actually, there is no need. 
Just by debugging, i can see that the method is only isn't called when setItemChecked is set to false.
It's not the code inside the onItemCheckedStateChanged that i have problems, it´s the actual method, that isn't called when false.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Seems like I also got it - onItemCheckedStateChanged isn't called on deselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

I have done with Custom Multiple Choice ListView that will solve your issue.
Go through the below link for comple source code.

**http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-custon-single-choice-lsitview.html**

This is a single choice listview.
You need to change and need to change to multipleChoice

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" />

Custom Multiple Choice ListView:-
```

[image]

Steps1)

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.custom.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements
        Checkable {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private List<Checkable> checkableViews;

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, int checkableId) {
        super(context);
        initialise(null);
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#isChecked()
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#setChecked(boolean)
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the custom XML attributes
     */
    private void initialise(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.isChecked = false;
        this.checkableViews = new ArrayList<Checkable>(5);
    }

    /**
     * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the
     * interface Checkable
     */
    private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
        if (v instanceof Checkable) {
            this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
                findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step2)

p

```
ackage com.custom.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
public class InertCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    public InertCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public InertCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InertCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Step3) listitem.xml

```
<com.custom.view.InertCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/multiitemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/singleitemId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/multiitemCheckBox"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Hope this help for you.

Comment: I'm affraid I can´t understand your answer, could you please elaborate  ?

Comment: @JuanuHaedo now see my complete answer. Plz let me know if you find any difficulties.

Comment: I would like first to try and solve the problem I'm having, instead of rewriting my code. In any case, I'll save it for later in case I can't solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved similar problem I had.

A few things to consider:

1. BaseAdapter by default doesn't have stable id's, while for select/deselect to work properly your adapter should have stable id's. Check AbsListView.java source code to confirm. So, override `hasStableIds()` method in your adapter implementation to return true and make sure `getItemId(int position)` return a unique id for each row.
2. Not sure if this second thing is really necessary, but just in case... By default implementation rows in the list aren't selectable - they display some highlight only while you hold your finger on the item. If you want do display some kind of static highlight and keep row selected - your item should implement `Checkable` interface. As for me - I used a custom `CheckableLinearLayout` implementation as the base for all my items. That worked. You can find implementation in the internet or write back to me I'll post one here.

And generally, I recommend looking into `AbsListView` source code, it can really help to understand what did go wrong